# want to use if condition in pom.xml

Tags: maven

I using two different xml file which I used for building the project from different location.

The build is done from jenkins then it used the pom.xml file and keystore which are defined there in pom.xml to sign any jar file .and i have another xml file which is ws.xml used to build the project and sign its jar file using differen keystore defined in the xml fil.

My question is below :

1.I want to put some conditional in pom.xml to check some parameter to decide which keystore i should use to sign the jar file as we use different keystore to sign the jar at diffferent location but i want to used respective keystore wherever the build process start.

->Build from jenkins used keystore defined in pom.xml.
->Build from any local build used keystore defined in ws.xml.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can solve this by using maven profiles. You can activate them explicitly on the command line (`mvn -m profileId`) or by setting environment variables.

See: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

You can configure a default in your pom.xml and then put the non-default settings in the profile. It sounds as if the keystore to be used could be in the `<properties>` of your pom. the profile would then just contain that same properties with different values.

Comment: Thanks for your response but the problem is that the has to be run through jenkins and this is where I got struck.can you please help how would i configure jenkins to activate a particular profile.can you please also tell me how can i do it using "setting environment variables" Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you can activate the profile in jenkings using the "Goals and Options" in the build configuration. For Example using "-Pmy-profile-id -DskipTests clean install" would clean install the project activating the my-profile-id maven profile